# Vue.js Slider element - v-model not working

Tags: vue.js

I'm trying to create a slider element to rate a movie on an app I'm building. Here's the part of my template:

`<input type="range" id="star-rating" min="0" max="5" step=".5" v-model="newReview.rating"/>`

`data() { return { newReview: { rating: 0, review: '' }`

The value of newReview.rating is not changing when I move the slider. Any help appreciated!

I've tried using this. in front of the v-model variable which I know isn't necessary.

Comment: You are missing closing brackets when defining `data`. You have 3 opening brackets and only 1 closing.

Comment: @MilosStojanovic IMO it seems obvious they didn't copy/paste their full code, otherwise the question would probably be about how to fix unrunnable code due to syntax errors rather than a specific question about v-model.

Comment: Accounting for missing brackets, the code in the question [does not reproduce the issue](https://play.vuejs.org/#eNp9UrFOwzAU/BXLS0Fq00oVSxUqAeoAA6DC6MVKXoOLY1v2cxoU5d95TtTQAVXJcO/u7NzZ6fiDc1kTgW94HgqvHG6FgdZZj6yEg4waWSdMKVHe3LKOecDoDQEDpz00Ck6bxEpUptqw1ZwMIzmbsT49wtCbL6e9aUConZYINDGWK+MiMvxxcC+4l6YCwZkqaQgo/WLcmqhaGeJWCcmW0B2hgOAIZgk3i9qWoGmcomXnxcstG75VqmbbdZPe9/kyUSngRSg+5xgKaw6qyo7BGjobOgLGBC9s7ZQG/+ZQWRMEp/JJSZrU2p5eBg59hPmZL76g+P6HP4Y2cYK/ewjgG6o9aVS8Ahzl3ccrtIQnkWpGTe4r4h6C1TFlHG2P0ZQU+8I3pH2u0z3TCX2GXYtgwrlUCpqc/eAXnH6QpyvV/+Kus/Wwjm6d978dY8le).  We need more information to reproduce.